# Graphics card issues with nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I’ve been having issues with my install of Ubuntu 20.04 not playing nice with my computer. My main issue is that I have some issues with black polygons in team fortress 2, which sent me on a long spiral which lead me to some interesting discoveries

My computer is using a nvidia gtx 1650, however in settings, my computer shows an intel 630. My nvidia x system setting app only shows profiles, and I cannot change anything in the app. I am using the 460 driver selected from additional drivers.

If anyone might be able to help, please do. I can post photos in the morning but I’m tired right now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to additional drivers (you can find it in applications list) and search for new video driver. You can can choose between proprietary or open source driver. I hope it helps

Comment: Hey, already tried that. I am currently on the Nvidia recommended driver, and I've played around with the drivers, but no change in the black polygons. My main query is about the nvidia settings not giving me anything to play around with, and the fact that my computer thinks my graphics card is an intel 630.